# Change applied taxes rate based on cart item quantity in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, tax

Is there a way to create a tax class that applies to a product based on the quantity of this product in the cart.

**Example:** If there is less then 6 items of the same product the taxes applies otherwise the taxes doesn't applies.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It is is possible.

First create in WooCommerce Tax settings a tax class named for example "Zero Rate" like:

1) in Tax options sections add "Zero Rate" and save:

[image]

2) A tab "Zero rate" appear. Under this tab section set the tax to zero:

[image]

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_taxes', 20, 1 );
function apply_conditionally_taxes( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( $cart_item['quantity'] >= 6 ){
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class('zero-rate');
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi Loic, Thanks for your answer it works like a charm! We added one another condition. Since your code applies to all products and we wanted to apply this no taxe on individual products. So, we created a option on a product. And when the cart get update we check if the product has this option it it. And then applies the tax in coincidence. Thanks again for this! !!!

Comment: Subtle note to add on to here, the tax class, if using get_tax_class(), will always be returned as a lowercase string with a dash in it, regardless of what the name is. So, if you have made a tax class of: "Zero Rate", it will be returned as "zero-rate".

Comment: @LoicTheAztec 
I'm noticing a problem here that if I update the cart quantity when I'm on the Cart page, the action doesn't get hooked and the quantity doesn't update. So, if I go from 6 products to 5 products, there is still no tax. Can you suggest another hook to use instead of woocommerce_before_calculate_totals that updates on the 'update' button in the cart next to the product?

Comment: @ntk4 **Not true !** as this hook is triggered every time cart contents change. The code works perfectly on last WooCommerce version. If is not the case is because some other customizations, a plugin or your theme that are making trouble.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you are right. I wasn't properly catching the item quantity in my function. I've reworked the function and all is good! Again, thank you so much for your help. It is nice to have a resource like this/you to help a fella like me!